# How to show that $2\int_{0}^{\infty}{\cosh(x)-1\over x(e^{ax}+1)} dx=\ln{4a\sin^2\left({\pi\over 2a}\right)\over \pi\sin\left({\pi\over a}\right)}?$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

How can we show that

> $$2\int_{0}^{\infty}{\cosh(x)-1\over x(e^{ax}+1)}\mathrm dx=\ln{4a\sin^2\left({\pi\over 2a}\right)\over \pi\sin\left({\pi\over a}\right)}?\tag1$$

Comment: This is not the first question you ask, and it might be a good moment for start adding your attempts in order to prevent downvotes and meet MSE's policy about questions.

Comment: You should not take it personally. We have nothing against you, but a policy is a policy, and MSE's policy is that every question needs an appropriate context. My personal opinion is that interesting questions deserve to stay open even if they lack attempts from the original poster, but you should not criticize people requesting you to add something to your bare questions. For instance, why do you ask them. That might be enough.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and I will do it next time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint**. One may observe that
$$
\int_0^{1} \sinh (y\cdot x) \, dy=\frac{\cosh (x)-1}{x},\qquad x>0,
$$ then one may obtain, for $a>1$,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\cosh(x)-1\over x(e^{ax}+1)}\mathrm dx&=\int_0^{1}dy\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sinh (y\cdot x)\over e^{ax}+1}\mathrm dx
\\\\&=\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{1}\left(\frac{\frac{\pi}{a}}{\sin \left(\frac{\pi  y}{a}\right)}-\frac{1}{y}\right)dy
\\\\&=\frac{1}{2}\ln \left(\frac{2a}{\pi}\cdot\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2a}\right)\right)
\end{align}
$$ where we have used the fact that
$$
\left(\frac{\ln \left(\tan \left(\frac{b y}{2}\right)\right)}{b}\right)'_y=\frac{1+\tan^2 \left(\frac{b y}{2}\right)}{2\tan \left(\frac{b y}{2}\right)}=\frac{1}{2\sin\left(\frac{b y}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{b y}{2}\right)}=\frac1{\sin\left(b y\right)}.
$$

Comment: That last step leaves me hanging :-/

Comment: I think you mean $a>1$, right?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Hope the last step is clear to you now ;).

Comment: @mickep Thank you very much for your remark, I've edited my answer.

Comment: @OlivierOloa Oh duh, sorry, my brain fart moment.  xD

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{2\int_{0}^{\infty}{\cosh\pars{x} - 1 \over x\pars{\expo{ax} + 1}}\,\dd x =
> \ln\pars{4a\sin^{2}\pars{\pi/\bracks{2a}} \over
>          \pi\sin\pars{\pi/a}}:\ {\large ?}}$.

\begin{align}
&2\int_{0}^{\infty}{\cosh\pars{x} - 1 \over x\pars{\expo{ax} + 1}}\,\dd x =
\,\mrm{f}\pars{1 - {1 \over a}} + \mrm{f}\pars{1 + {1 \over a}}
\label{1}\tag{1}
\\[5mm] &\mbox{where}\quad
\mrm{f}\pars{z} \equiv
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{-zax} - \expo{-ax} \over x\pars{1 + \expo{-ax}}}\,\dd x
\label{2}\tag{2}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
\mrm{f}\pars{z} & \equiv
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{-zax} - \expo{-ax} \over x\pars{1 + \expo{-ax}}}\,\dd x
\,\,\,\,\,\,\stackrel{\pars{\substack{{\large\expo{-ax}\ =\ t}\\[0.5mm]
                     {\large x\ =\ -\ln\pars{t}/a}}}\\[2mm]
                     \mbox{}}{\Large=}\,\,\,\,\,\,
-\int_{0}^{1}{t^{z - 1} - 1 \over \ln\pars{t}\pars{1 + t}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{0}^{1}{t^{z - 1} - 1 \over 1 - t^{2}}\,{t - 1 \over \ln\pars{t}}\,\dd t =
\int_{0}^{1}{t^{z - 1} - 1 \over 1 - t^{2}}\int_{0}^{1}t^{s}\,\dd s\,\dd t =
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}{t^{s + z - 1} - t^{s} \over 1 - t^{2}}\,\dd t\,\dd s
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{t^{2}\ \mapsto\ t}{=}\,\,\,
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}
{t^{s/2 + z/2 - 1} - t^{s/2 - 1/2} \over 1 - t}\,\dd t\,\dd s
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}\pars{%
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - t^{s/2 - 1/2} \over 1 - t}\,\dd t -
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - t^{s/2 + z/2- 1} \over 1 - t}\,\dd t}\,\dd s
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{%
\Psi\pars{s + 1 \over 2} - \Psi\pars{s + z \over 2}}
\dd s\qquad\pars{~\Psi:\ Digamma\ Function~}
\\[5mm] & =
\left.\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{\pars{s + 1}/2} \over \Gamma\pars{\bracks{s + z}/2}}
\right\vert_{\ s\ =\ 0}^{\ s\ =\ 1} =
\ln\pars{{\Gamma\pars{1} \over \Gamma\pars{\bracks{1 + z}/2}}\,
{\Gamma\pars{z/2} \over \Gamma\pars{1/2}}}
\\[5mm] & \implies
\bbx{\mrm{f}\pars{z} = \ln\pars{{1 \over \root{\pi}}\,{\Gamma\pars{z/2} \over \Gamma\pars{\bracks{1 + z}/2}}}}
\end{align}

> \eqref{1} is reduced to

\begin{align}
&2\int_{0}^{\infty}{\cosh\pars{x} - 1 \over x\pars{\expo{ax} + 1}}\,\dd x =
\ln\pars{{1 \over \root{\pi}}
{\Gamma\pars{1/2 - 1/\bracks{2a}} \over \Gamma\pars{1 - 1/\bracks{2a}}}\,
{1 \over \root{\pi}}
{\Gamma\pars{1/2 + 1/\bracks{2a}} \over \Gamma\pars{1 + 1/\bracks{2a}}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\ln\pars{{1 \over \pi}\,{\pi \over \sin\pars{\pi\braces{1/2 + 1/\bracks{2a}}}}\,
{1 \over \Gamma\pars{1 - 1/\bracks{2a}}\Gamma\pars{1/\bracks{2a}}/\bracks{2a}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\ln\pars{{2a \over \cos\pars{\pi/\bracks{2a}}}\,
{1 \over \pi/\sin\pars{\pi/\bracks{2a}}}} =
\ln\pars{{4a \over \pi}\,{\sin^{2}\pars{\pi/\bracks{2a}} \over 2\sin\pars{\pi/\bracks{2a}}\cos\pars{\pi/\bracks{2a}}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{\ln\pars{4a\sin^{2}\pars{\pi/\bracks{2a}} \over \pi\sin\pars{\pi/a}}}
\end{align}

> Indeed, a simpler expression is
>   $\bbx{\ds{\ln\pars{{2a \over \pi}\,\tan\pars{\pi \over 2a}}}}$.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach. By Frullani's theorem
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cosh(x)-1}{x}e^{-\mu x}\,dx = \log\mu-\frac{1}{2}\log(\mu^2-1)\tag{1}$$
for any $\mu>1$. By expanding $\frac{1}{e^{ax}+1}$ as a geometric series
$$ \frac{1}{1+e^{ax}} = e^{-ax}-e^{-2a x}+e^{-3ax}-e^{-4ax}+\ldots \tag{2} $$
the original integral equals
$$ \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k\geq 1}(-1)^{k+1}\left[\log(k^2a^2)-\log(k^2 a^2-1)\right]=\frac{1}{2}\,\log\frac{\prod_{k\geq 1}\left(1-\frac{1}{(2k)^2 a^2}\right)}{\prod_{k\geq 0}\left(1-\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2 a^2}\right)}\tag{3} $$
and the claim follows from the Weierstrass product for the sine and cosine functions.